# Regex match multiple same expression multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

I have got this string `{bgRed Please run a task, {red a list has been provided below}`, I need to do a string replace to remove the braces and also the first word.

So below I would want to remove `{bgRed` and `{red` and then the trailing brace which I can do separate.

I have managed to create this regex, but it is only matching `{bgRed` and not `{red`, can someone lend a hand?

`/^\{.+?(?=\s)/gm`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I would want to have the matching result to be `{bgRed` and `{red`

Comment: But you mentioned replacing...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note you are using `^` anchor at the start and that makes your pattern only match at the start of a line (mind also the `m` modifier). `.+?(?=\s|$)` is too cumbersome, you want to match any 1+ chars up to the first whitespace or end of string, use `{\S+` (or `{\S*` if you plan to match `{` without any non-whitespace chars after it).

You may use

```
s = s.replace(/{\S*|}/g, '')
```

You may trim the outcome to get rid of resulting leading/trailing spaces:

```
s = s.replace(/{\S*|}/g, '').trim()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iho2Ba/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%7B%5CS*%7C%7D):

[image]

**Details**

- `{\S*` - `{` char followed with 0 or more non-whitespace characters
- `|` - or
- `}` - a `}` char.

Comment: Fyi, these leaves two extra spaces in the sentence.

Comment: That's spot on! Thanks. Yeah could do with removing that extra space to be fair, but I can just add `\s` ? So `{\S*\s|}`?

Comment: @ruohola `trim()` is a natural solution to those spaces. Others can also be dealt with easily, but that is not the requirement.

Comment: @MartynBall If you wish, yes, you may even use `.replace(/\s*(?:{\S*\s*|})\s*/g, ' ').trim()` if you are not interested in keeping spaces around the matches.

Comment: @MartynBall I added some more explanation at the top.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is go to from

```
"{bgRed Please run a task, {red a list has been provided below}"
```

to

```
"Please run a task, a list has been provided below"
```

a regex with two capture groups seems simplest:

```js
const original = "{bgRed Please run a task, {red a list has been provided below}";
const rex = /\{\w+ ([^{]+)\{\w+ ([^}]+)}/g;
const result = original.replace(rex, "$1$2");
console.log(result);
```

`\{\w+ ([^{]+)\{\w+ ([^}]+)}` is:

- `\{` - a literal `{`
- `\w+` - one or more word characters ("bgRed")
- a  literal space
- `([^{]+)` one or more characters that aren't `{`, captured to group 1
- `\{` - another literal `{`
- `\w+` - one or more word characters ("red")
- `([^}]+)` - one or more characters that aren't `}`, captured to group 2
- `}` - a literal `}`

The replacement uses `$1` and `$2` to swap in the capture group contents.

Comment: Thanks! Wiktor beat you to it so I will accept his answer as it works.

Comment: @MartynBall - No worries. Note that Wiktor's answer is much more general, it replaces `{` followed by words and `}` without regard to the overall format. The above is much more specific to the overall format. Whether you want general or specific will depend on your use case. :-)

Comment: @MartynBall Why "beat"? It's a different answer and also an interesting approach. It's not about who throws in the first piece. Often the first answers are not the best answers.

Comment: @bobblebubble - Although if they're Wiktor's and it's about regex, they usually are. :-D